# Is there a way to draw shapes so that their fills act as opaque within the group but are transparent towards the background

Tags: svg, webgl, pixi.js

I'm trying to find tools to render a group of overlapping shapes so that within the group the fill acts as opaque (so the overlapped circle outlines are not shown), but at the same time the fills of group members are transparent to any background layers underneath.

I hope this picture will make it clearer:

[image: picture showing the current and the desired state]

What I'm able to accomplish is a bunch of circles with empty fills (d in the image). What I would like to achieve (h in the image) is circle outlines being hidden in the overlaps so that the layering in the outlined circle group is clear, but the group as a whole having a transparent fill so that the background layer (blue-filled bubbles in the picture) is visible.

The perimeter of the circles in the group would be determined by data and possibly dynamic so I guess they need to be identifiable as separate objects, so I cannot turn them into some kind of compound path to get what I need.

From what I found, this cannot be done in SVG or CSS alone, so I wonder if there is some knock-out filter or any kind of solution within Pixi.js or general WebGL that would allow me to set a different transparency behaviour within the layer and different towards other layers.

Comment: can you use a [`<mask>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask) when you draw each white circles and then not use it when you draw the light blue ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps.

You can add more circles as desired. The mask circles overlap each other but as a whole when applied to the rectangle the masked parts are transparent.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
  <defs>
    <mask id="circle-mask" width="1" height="1" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <circle cx="0.2" cy="0.2" r="0.1" stroke="white" stroke-width="0.01"/>  
      <circle cx="0.3" cy="0.3" r="0.1" stroke="white" stroke-width="0.01"/>  
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="30" cy="60" r="20" fill="blue" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
  <rect width="200" height="200" mask= "url(#circle-mask)" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```